# Qustion regarding telnet to a switch on the network and sending in specific commands

Tags: python

I have written a python program to telnet to a switch on the network, login and enter specific commands. But I don't know what is wrong with my program as the program never gets passed through after login. I doubt the program is even taking in the password I gave at command line.

Here is my program:

```
import telnetlib
import getpass
import sys

Host = "10.210.1.2"
user = raw_input("hbommireddy")
password = getpass.getpass()


tn = telnetlib.Telnet(Host)
tn.read_until("Login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")
tn.read_until("SYSTEM-QA-S4810>")
tn.write("en\n")

tn.read_until("SYSTEM-QA-S4810#")
tn.write("show interface status\n")

print tn.read_all()
```

Comment: If i telnet to this switch manually o/p looks like the following: Login: hbommireddy
Password:
SYSTEM-QA-S4810>en
SYSTEM-QA-S4810#show interface status
Port     Description  Status Speed     Duplex Vlan
Te 0/0   C300-SysQA   Up     10000 Mbit Full   --
Te 0/1   Dell-C300-4  Up     10000 Mbit Full   1
Te 0/2   UK-Uplink-S  Up     1000 Mbit Auto   --
Te 0/3   USA-Uplink   Up     1000 Mbit Auto   2,349
Te 0/4   Brazil-Japa  Up     1000 Mbit Auto   --
Te 0/5   Performance  Down   Auto      Auto   9
Te 0/6                Down   Auto      Auto   7

Comment: And how are you calling your script from the command line?

Comment: Hi Drewnes,I am using windows and i am executing this telnet11.py python file from the folder where it is located on cmd.

Comment: Try putting `print password` under `password = getpass.getpass()`. Then run your script. You should see the password and confirm it's getting set.

Comment: Hi Drewness, ok. I did that and it is printing the password now after i enter my password.But nothing after that :(